# Why is FormArray value not updated when I edit input field?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I have angular reactive form consisting of few FormControl and one FormArray element.

```
competitionForm!: FormGroup;    
    
this.competitionForm = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(this.competition.name, []),
  about: new FormControl(this.competition.about, []),
  rules: new FormControl(this.competition.rules, []),
  competitorNames: new FormArray([]),
});
```

`competitorNames` contains array of FormControl with string as a value. I connected `competitionForm` with form on my html template. I am using custom input (app-input) component. It gets FormControl as input: [control].

```
<form [formGroup]="competitionForm">    
    <div formArrayName="competitorNames">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let competitor of refCompetitorNames.controls">
          <app-input
            [control]="$any(competitor)"
            [placeholder]="'name'"
            [type]="'text'"
          ></app-input>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
</form>
```

```
get refCompetitorNames() {
  return this.competitionForm.get('competitorNames') as FormArray;
}
```

Getting form data with `this.competitionForm.value.competitorNames` is **always returning same data**. It does not change when I enter new value in input element. Also, input elements are displayed with values inside. That means template form is binded with `competitionForm`.

This approach works when used on FormControl, but there is a problem with FormArray elements. Here is how template looks for single FormControl. Here I get updated data (if any input is changed) as I should.

Difference is in how I pass control.

```
<form [formGroup]="competitionForm">    
    <app-input
        [control]="$any(competitionForm.controls).name"
        [placeholder]="'name'"
        [type]="'text'"
      ></app-input>
</form>
```

edit: **Problem solved**

I found where was the problem. Solution is to access form data in different way. With `this.refCompetitorNames.at(i).value` I get correct data.

I still don't know why `this.competitionForm.value.competitorNames` is not returning updated data (only in this case with FormArray).

Comment: I push formcontrols with data I get from backend. That data is displayed, only problem is about editing.

Comment: I've used a similar approach before but I haven't used it with ng-container. This is total shot in the dark, but maybe move your *ngFor down to the app-input element. It might be that using it with ng-container is causing some issue that I couldn't explain without examining the source code

Comment: Found solution, look at edit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried moving *ngFor to app-input but it didn't solve the issue. (anyway I found other solution that works)

Comment: glad you found something! you should share your solution for anyone looking later
edit: post as answer I mean

Comment: Oh I did not know I could answer to my question. Here it is.

Answer (score 0):

I found where was the problem. Solution is to access form data in different way. With `this.refCompetitorNames.at(i).value` I get correct data.

I still don't know why `this.competitionForm.value.competitorNames` is not returning updated data (only in this case with FormArray).

Comment: In old versions of Angular there're a "delay" between `this.refCompetitorNames.at(i).value` and `this.competitionForm.value.competitorNames` (in a submit the two values are the same). I don't know when you want to access the value or what version of Angular you're using -I think, but not sure, since Angular 12 always have the same value-

Comment: Two values weren't same on submit. That is how I noticed bug. I have edit form where name, about and rules were updated but not competitorNames. After printing it's value I saw it is always the same. I am using Angular 14.